# cannot insert into NSMutableArray due to indexvalue being out of bounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a MutableArray on this view called array and the object in question is `detailItem`, which has a property of `rank` (int). On this view, there's a text field displaying the rank and I want to be able to move the `detailItem` up and down the MutableArray by changing the rank.

So, for example let's say the `detailItem` has a rank of 3, which is index value of 2. If I change this in the text field to 3, I want the array to adjust and move it down one place. However, as I type in the value of `rankField` (the text field), it crashes the app since it automatically updates the value before I'm done editing. So, if I click on the text field and write 23 (planing on deleting the 2) or just press delete (now the value is nil) the app crashes with an uncaught exception.

Here's the code:

```
- (IBAction)rankFIeldTextChanged:(id)sender {
  QueueMember *member = self.detailItem;
  [self.array removeObjectAtIndex:self.detailItem.rank];

  if (0<= [self.rankField.text intValue]<= self.array.count) {
    [self.array insertObject:member atIndex:[self.rankField.text intValue]-1];
  }
}
```

The if condition of making the text value in-between the array size and 0 seems to have no effect.

btw this is all in the detailsViewController which is connected to the main view controller via push segue. does it make more sense(or more better coding) to just set the new rank value in details and actually make the array changes in the mainviewcontroller.m?

Comment: That's *pseudo code*, right?

Comment: no i copy/pasted that straight from xcode.

Comment: How does it compile?  `0 <= intValue <= count` is nothing I've seen before...

Comment: @trojanfoe - Simple: `YES/NO <= self.array.count`.

Comment: im pretty new to coding so Im not sure if my statement is correct but xcode says there's no issues, it just crashes when i run and activate the editing rankField feature

Comment: That's because zero or 1 is almost always less than `self.array.count`.  Your `if` statement first computes a boolean 0/1 value based on the first compare, then compares that result to self.array.count in the second compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to do two boolean statements at once (which doesn't work).  Change your if statement to something like:

```
if (0< [self.rankField.text intValue] && [self.rankField.text intValue] < self.array.count) {
    //Insert your object here
}
else
{
    //Add object here
}
```

Your current setup check to see if `0<= [self.rankField.text intValue]`, which will return true for all values greater than or equal to 0.  Then it checks the result of that (YES:1, NO:0) if it's less than or equal to your array count.  That will always return true if your array has anything in it.  So basically your check will always return true.

Since it always returns true I could check for array object number 1000, your if statement says go for it, then I check and the array says "No way in heck!" and crashes your app.

EDIT:  Updated my code snippet to take into account your array insertion line.

Comment: i changed it to what u suggested and the uncaught exception error still arises, when i press delete and there's momentarily nothing in the textfield it crashes and says beyond bound.

Comment: @snapfish I updated my response to take into account your inserting code.  You need to check that you are greater than and less than, not equal to in any case.

Comment: what if i have 5 items in my array and i want to move item2 to the end of the list? wouldnt i enter 5 as the rank (index:4) and that would be equal to the array count so this if statement wouldnt run? also would my array at that point technically be only 4 items since item2 is removed already?

Comment: so if i use item3 in an array of three items as an example, if i change the rank from 3 to 3 (i.e. just retype it) nothing should change but the app crashes telling me Im beyond bounds. would u suggest to due this array editing in the mainviewcontroller instead?

Comment: It's basic arithmetic.  You have three items, and you modify number 3.  Your code takes out number 3, so now you have two, then it tries to insert at spot 3 which is now out of your array bounds.  I think you need to rethink how your modifications are working.  Why not use a `NSDictionary` instead?

Comment: i think a NSMutableArray better suits my purposes. I'v decided to pass the new rank information back to the mainviewcontroller and make changes to the array there as that is the original location of the array. Thank you for all your help though, I learned a few new things.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just do this

```
- (IBAction)rankFIeldTextChanged:(id)sender {
  QueueMember *member = self.detailItem;
  [self.array removeObjectAtIndex:self.detailItem.rank];

  if ((0<= [self.rankField.text intValue])&&([self.rankField.text intValue]<= self.array.count)) {

     if (self.array.count >([self.rankField.text intValue]-1)){
        [self.array insertObject:member atIndex:[self.rankField.text intValue]-1];
    }
  }
}
```

you are probably trying to insert at an index greater than the count of the array.

Comment: it still doesnt allow of a proper editing because the array is smaller once the removeObjectAtIndex is called so the arraycount that is returned is smaller than it should be. i think im going to try to simply send the value of the rank back to the mainviewcontroller and edit the mutable array there.